# Is it possible to get Chrome to honour backface-visibility: hidden when set on an element container a canvas with a WebGL context?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, webgl

This appears to be a bug with Chrome, but just in case someone has come up with a simple CSS workaround. I've filed a [bug report with a test case](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=738675) and there is also a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alexprokop/9a982bfr/). The issue is when transforming an element with `backface-visibility: hidden`. If there is a child element with a WebGL context, Chrome will display it anyway. Setting `transform-style: preserve-3d` or `backface-visibility: hidden` directly on the canvas make no difference. It works correctly if the transform is only applied to the canvas itself, but unfortunately my use case makes this impossible.

```js
function drawWebGL ( canvas ) {
    var gl = canvas.getContext( 'webgl' );
    gl.clearColor( 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1 );
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
}

drawWebGL( document.querySelector( 'canvas' ) );
```

```css
.container {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #f00;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    padding: 17px;
}

@keyframes spinY {
  from { transform: rotateY(  0deg); }
  to   { transform: rotateY(360deg); }
}

.container.-flip {
    border: 1px solid red;
    animation: spinY 4s infinite linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="container -flip">
  <canvas width="66" height="66"></canvas>
</div>

<div class="container -flip">
  <div>some text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's looks pretty clearly to be a bug