# flipping animation in div not hiding canvas. Expected behavior is hide canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/guradio/pcds6xj3/)

I want to have a div that can be flipped back and forth. My first div can contain anything. My second contains a canvas using `chart.js`. I want to flip these two div and I want to hide the other on click of a button on the left most part of the page.

Problem is that cans is not hiding just flipping. But the other is hidden if the canvas is the current page. While the canvas just flip on the other side if the other is the current div.

```js
document.getElementById('shortcut').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('side-2').className = 'flip flip-side-1';
  document.getElementById('side-1').className = 'flip flip-side-2';
}, false);

document.getElementById('budget').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('side-2').className = 'flip';
  document.getElementById('side-1').className = 'flip';
}, false);

var data = [{
  value: 300,
  color: "#F7464A",
  highlight: "#FF5A5E",
  label: "Red"
  //filter: 1
}, {
  value: 50,
  color: "#46BFBD",
  highlight: "#5AD3D1",
  label: "Green"
  //filter: 2
}, {
  value: 100,
  color: "#FDB45C",
  highlight: "#FFC870",
  label: "Yellow"
  //filter: 3
}]

$(document).ready(function() {
  var ctx = $("#chart").get(0).getContext("2d");
  var chart = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(data);

  var segments = chart.segments;
  for (var i = 0; i < segments.length; i++) {
    // Add properties in here like this
    segments[i].filter = i + 1;
  }

  $("#chart").click(
    function(evt) {
      var activePoints = chart.getSegmentsAtEvent(evt);
      console.log(activePoints);
      var url = "http://example.com/?grid[f][collor][]=" + activePoints[0].filter
      alert(url);
    }
  );
});
```

```css
canvas {
  //height: 10vh; 
  width: 90vw;
  display: block;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.flip {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
  height: 100%;
  font: normal 14px helvetica, arial, san serif;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px;
  transition: all 3s;
  -moz-transition: all 3s;
  -ms-transition: all 3s;
  -o-transition: all 3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s;
}

#side-1 {
  transform: rotateY( 0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY( 0deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 0deg);
}

#side-2 {
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

.flip-side-1 {
  transform: rotateY( 0deg) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 0deg) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotateY( 0deg) !important;
  -o-transform: rotateY( 0deg) !important;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 0deg) !important;
}

.flip-side-2 {
  transform: rotateY( 180deg) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotateY( 180deg) !important;
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg) !important;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg) !important;
}

.separator {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25px;
  background: skyblue;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js"></script>
<div id="side-1" class="flip">
  <span class="separator" id="shortcut"></span>
  <div class="vPadding black"></div>
</div>
<div id="side-2" class="flip">
  <span class="separator" id="budget"></span>
  <div class="vPadding">
    <canvas id="chart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works properly in e.g. Firefox but not Chrome. [This bug was discussed for Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=99812) in 2011/2012, looked fixed, re-appeared, then again looked fixed. A similar issue was [discussed here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44860505/is-it-possible-to-get-chrome-to-honour-backface-visibility-hidden-when-set-on-a) two weeks ago. So, looks like a recurring bug that has reared its head again.

Comment: @AndrewWillems I need to make it work on Chrome any idea how to fix this bug ?

Comment: I fought with the code for a while and I'm strongly suspecting that it is currently unfixable. I tried setting a background colour behind the canvas thinking that maybe with a solid background that becomes hidden, that might magically hide the canvas. Turns out the background does get hidden, but the canvas still stays visible, alas. I'll take a look at it again, but if you don't hear back from me, I'll have found nothing....

Comment: Best bet: pester Google to fix the bug: The [first link from my first comment](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=99812) has the following comment: "This issue has been closed for some time. No one will pay attention to new comments. If you are seeing this bug or have new data, please click New Issue to start a new bug." Go to that page and click the "New Issue" button in the top left corner. I recognize that that's probably not going to be a quick fix but it might be the only thing you can do.

Comment: @AndrewWillems i see.. thank you for the effort that you have given on this post.. hopefully when you get a solution you can share it here. I will try to find a solution myself thanks to resources you have provided. again thank you very much..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is admittedly an ugly hack, but *perhaps* it might accomplish what you need until Google fixes the bug in the Chrome browser that causes this problem in the first place.

I essentially just overlaid a second animation on top of the flipping, making the canvas disappear at approximately the half-way point of the flip. This ends up not being 1.5 seconds into the 3 second flip, probably because the flip uses some sort of easing function that makes the "half-way" point occur at a different time. By trial and error, I found that making the canvas disappear after 0.9 seconds worked. Note, however, that I didn't check any of the other browsers, which may use different easing functions.

I also don't know if this will accomplish what you need in terms of showing appropriate things in the background, re-painting the screen etc. Hopefully, though, it might be at least a starting point for you to figure out a better hack yourself.

Note that I can't tell from your question whether you want the canvas to start being hidden or start being visible. The fact that you have an animation at the very beginning when the chart is created suggests to me that the canvas should start visible. However, the direction of the text upon mousing over the chart segments suggests that the chart should start hidden.

```js
document.getElementById('shortcut').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('side-2').className = 'flip flip-side-1';
  document.getElementById('side-1').className = 'flip flip-side-2';
  document.getElementById('chart').className = 'canvas-appear';
  document.getElementById('chart').className = 'canvas-appear';
}, false);

document.getElementById('budget').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('side-2').className = 'flip';
  document.getElementById('side-1').className = 'flip';
  document.getElementById('chart').className = 'canvas-disappear';
  document.getElementById('chart').className = 'canvas-disappear';
}, false);

var data = [{
  value: 300,
  color: "#F7464A",
  highlight: "#FF5A5E",
  label: "Red"
  //filter: 1
}, {
  value: 50,
  color: "#46BFBD",
  highlight: "#5AD3D1",
  label: "Green"
  //filter: 2
}, {
  value: 100,
  color: "#FDB45C",
  highlight: "#FFC870",
  label: "Yellow"
  //filter: 3
}]

$(document).ready(function() {
  var ctx = $("#chart").get(0).getContext("2d");
  var chart = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(data);

  var segments = chart.segments;
  for (var i = 0; i < segments.length; i++) {
    // Add properties in here like this
    segments[i].filter = i + 1;
  }

  $("#chart").click(
    function(evt) {
      var activePoints = chart.getSegmentsAtEvent(evt);
      console.log(activePoints);
      var url = "http://example.com/?grid[f][collor][]=" + activePoints[0].filter
      alert(url);
    }
  );
});
```

```css
canvas {
  //height: 10vh; 
  width: 90vw;
  display: block;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.flip {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
  height: 100%;
  font: normal 14px helvetica, arial, san serif;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px;
  transition: all 3s;
}

#side-1 {
  transform: rotateY( 0deg);
}

#side-2 {
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

.flip-side-1 {
  transform: rotateY( 0deg) !important;
}

.flip-side-2 {
  transform: rotateY( 180deg) !important;
}

.separator {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25px;
  background: skyblue;
  z-index: 999;
}

#chart {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.canvas-disappear {
  animation: 0.75s disappear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes disappear {
  99% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

.canvas-appear {
  animation: 0.9s appear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  visibility: hidden;
}

@keyframes appear {
  99% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js"></script>
<div id="side-1" class="flip">
  <span class="separator" id="shortcut"></span>
  <div class="vPadding black"></div>
</div>
<div id="side-2" class="flip">
  <span class="separator" id="budget"></span>
  <div class="vPadding">
    <canvas id="chart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could be a solution by hiding the canvas.. i tried it before but i didnt target the canvas itself and it still didnt hide.. looks like you need to target the canvas itself :)